# How do I create a subtle flipper motion?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I would like my flippers to move in a way similar to the front and back flippers in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2252Nxzet6U

[image]

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise what problem you're struggling with. The text below the video says it's a full rigged Ichthyosaurus with a swimming cycle. Do you have problems rigging your flippers? Or creating the swimming cycle? And what is exactly the problem or do you want a complete tutorial on rigging and cyclic animations?

Comment: +1 to Gordon's comment ... please ad more details otherwise you risk closing your Q for not enough details or clarity. Also next time don't base your question on external links, that can be broken in a future, it means not helpful for others to learn from your question. This site is meant to be a knowledge base. Thank you to keep this site useful.

Answer (score 2):

### version Modifies

Even this site does not support this kind of question and I fully support Gordon's comment ... I did similar kind of simple motion without armature ...

- add a *Plane* along Z axis, divide it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and assign **Wave modifier**. If you want keep a head static use *Weight Paint* to define how much modifier should affect the Plane and use automatically created *Vertex Group* in modifier.

[image]

- than for your fish model add **Surface Deform** modifier > Target your *Plane* and *Bind*

[image]

Comment: so his head is moving and he is opening and closing his mouth....

Comment: @vklidu Yep, nice and quick solution. But with regard to Chris' comment and what we said about lack of clarity... this creates a "subtle flipper motion" overall like mentioned in the title, but "to move in a similar way" like in the question... the original video also has individual movements of each flipper and the head etc.

Comment: @vklidu Yeah, and I said it's nice and easy and upvoted it, so why do you get offended so quickly? And sorry for the "discussion", I sometimes have a faint hope that also OPs read comments and get a hint out of it how they can make things clearer.

Comment: @vklidu I addressed you for the first sentence, "nice and quick solution." The rest was to addressed to nobody in particular, just a general wondering about what to do if someone wants more movement like in the video. For example I can't really see if the flippers do some very subtle up and down and maybe even slightly cycling movement... and I wouldn't know how to do that with the answer.